# How to train a two tower model using TensorFlow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have referred the blog below but not able to get the architecture and what model does there
https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/09/introducing-tensorflow-recommenders.html

Also went through different papers like

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/This-figure-illustrates-our-models-two-tower-CNN-based-encoder-decoder-architecture_fig1_318899300

It explains well but tough when tried implement those.